# MySQL can't restart after lower_case_tables_names changed

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I am trying to channge lower_case_tables_names to value 1 on Ubuntu 17.10, but when I got an error on mysql start, when lower_case_tables_name=1:

```
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 audit[2657]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2657/status" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 audit[2657]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 audit[2657]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2657/status" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=109
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1509446172.174:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2657/status" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" deni
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1509446172.174:87): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask=
Oct 31 13:36:12 www-v2 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1509446172.174:88): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2657/status" pid=2657 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" deni
Oct 31 13:36:14 www-v2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

When lower_case_tables_name=0 mysql starts correct.

How to switch mysql to lower_case_tables_name=1 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Thank you!

Comment: did you mean lower_case_table_name**s** ?